# Missing map marker using Google Maps SDK for iOS v2.6.0

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm following the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) to experiment with Google Maps using the iOS Simulator. Everything seems in order except for the missing marker.

```
func addMarker(lat: Double, lng: Double) {
  let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng))
  marker.title = "Orlando"
  marker.snippet = "Florida"
  marker.map = mapView

  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 15.0)
  mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
  view = mapView
  print("addMarker(lat:\(lat), lng:\(lng))")
}
```

The map renders. The camera shows the GPS location in view. The print statement is logged. However, the marker pin doesn't appear.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are changing `MapView` instance after adding marker to `old MapView` instance. Means you added Marker to `old MapView` instance and you are looking for that Marker in `new MapView` instance. Try like this,

```
func addMarker(lat: Double, lng: Double) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 15.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng))
    marker.title = "Orlando"
    marker.snippet = "Florida"
    marker.map = mapView

    print("addMarker(lat:\(lat), lng:\(lng))")
}
```

Thanks.